# Unable to resolve host address while installing neo4j database on ubuntu 16.04. How to solve this?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, database, neo4j

How to solve this?

```
sudo wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
--2018-07-07 17:23:46--  https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key
Resolving debian.neo4j.org (debian.neo4j.org)... 
failed: Name or service not known.

wget: unable to resolve host address ‘debian.neo4j.org’

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command

```
host debian.neo4j.org
```

returns

```
debian.neo4j.org is an alias for outreach.neotechnology.com.
outreach.neotechnology.com has address 52.0.233.188
```

As temporary solution add line

```
52.0.233.188    debian.neo4j.org
```

to `/etc/hosts` file.

Additionally use for the debian.neo4j.org host --no-check-certificate option:

```
wget -O- --no-check-certificate https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```